Building Kivy App to APK using buildozer fails on Google Colab
I am using Google Colab
I have 2 files, main.py and main.kv
I updated the spec file and the build process continues till I get an error in confige.ac
I tried running !autoupdate but I got this error autoupdate: error: 'configure.ac' is required
I tried updating everything but it was at the latest version.
I assume it is a problem with using a virtual environment, but I used the same steps before and compiled 2 different apps
Full Error:
Exception in thread background thread for pid 39574:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
autoreconf: export WARNINGS=
autoreconf: Entering directory '.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Intltool
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gtkdoc
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
configure.ac:8: warning: The macro `AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM' is obsolete.
configure.ac:8: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2081: AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM is expanded from...
configure.ac:8: the top level
configure.ac:74: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:74: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:3: AC_FUNC_MMAP_BLACKLIST is expanded from...
configure.ac:74: the top level
configure.ac:91: warning: The macro `AC_HEADER_STDC' is obsolete.
configure.ac:91: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:704: AC_HEADER_STDC is expanded from...
configure.ac:91: the top level
configure.ac:118: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:118: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
m4/asmcfi.m4:1: GCC_AS_CFI_PSEUDO_OP is expanded from...
configure.ac:118: the top level
configure.ac:122: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:122: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:122: the top level
configure.ac:138: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:138: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:138: the top level
configure.ac:185: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:185: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:185: the top level
configure.ac:215: warning: _LT_CMD_GLOBAL_SYMBOLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
aclocal.m4:778: LT_SYS_SYMBOL_USCORE is expanded from...
configure.ac:215: the top level
configure.ac:310: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
configure.ac:310: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
configure.ac:310: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: AC_PROG_LD is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_RUN' is obsolete.
configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2997: AC_TRY_RUN is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:41: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure:8578: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LD
autoreconf: error: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1256, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 685, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 104, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 163, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 504, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 28, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.Command('./autogen.sh'), _env=env)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
autoreconf: export WARNINGS=
autoreconf: Entering directory '.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Intltool
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gtkdoc
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
configure.ac:8: warning: The macro `AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM' is obsolete.
configure.ac:8: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2081: AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM is expanded from...
configure.ac:8: the top level
configure.ac:74: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:74: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:3: AC_FUNC_MMAP_BLACKLIST is expanded from...
configure.ac:74: the top level
configure.ac:91: warning: The macro `AC_HEADER_STDC' is obsolete.
configure.ac:91: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:704: AC_HEADER_STDC is expanded from...
configure.ac:91: the top level
configure.ac:118: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:118: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
m4/asmcfi.m4:1: GCC_AS_CFI_PSEUDO_OP is expanded from...
configure.ac:118: the top level
configure.ac:122: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:122: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:122: the top level
configure.ac:138: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:138: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:138: the top level
configure.ac:185: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:185: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:185: the top level
configure.ac:215: warning: _LT_CMD_GLOBAL_SYMBOLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
aclocal.m4:778: LT_SYS_SYMBOL_USCORE is expanded from...
configure.ac:215: the top level
configure.ac:310: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
configure.ac:310: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
configure.ac:310: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: AC_PROG_LD is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_RUN' is obsolete.
configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2997: AC_TRY_RUN is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:41: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure:8578: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LD
autoreconf: error: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1


  STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=beam', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy,socket', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_VERSION = '12.2.5.6-1'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_TRANSPORT = 'ipc'
#     NV_NVML_DEV_VERSION = '12.2.140-1'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcudnn8'
#     CGROUP_MEMORY_EVENTS = '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory.events /var/colab/cgroup/jupyter-children/memory.events'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnccl-dev=2.19.3-1+cuda12.2'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.19.3-1'
#     VM_GCE_METADATA_HOST = '169.254.169.253'
#     HOSTNAME = '9699e42a1015'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_US'
#     TBE_RUNTIME_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8011'
#     COLAB_TPU_1VM = ''
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=12.2 brand=tesla,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=unknown,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=nvidia,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=nvidiartx,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=geforce,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=geforcertx,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=quadro,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=quadrortx,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=titan,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=titanrtx,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=tesla,driver>=525,driver<526 '
 'brand=unknown,driver>=525,driver<526 brand=nvidia,driver>=525,driver<526 '
 'brand=nvidiartx,driver>=525,driver<526 brand=geforce,driver>=525,driver<526 '
 'brand=geforcertx,driver>=525,driver<526 brand=quadro,driver>=525,driver<526 '
 'brand=quadrortx,driver>=525,driver<526 brand=titan,driver>=525,driver<526 '
 'brand=titanrtx,driver>=525,driver<526')
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-dev-12-2=12.2.5.6-1'
#     NV_NVTX_VERSION = '12.2.140-1'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_IP = '172.28.0.12'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_DEV_VERSION = '12.2.140-1'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_VERSION = '12.1.2.141-1'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY_ROOT_URL = 'http://172.28.0.1:8013/'
#     NV_LIBNPP_VERSION = '12.2.1.4-1'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.19.3-1'
#     KMP_LISTEN_PORT = '6000'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = '30s'
#     TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE = 'libcudnn8=8.9.6.50-1+cuda12.2'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_TOKEN = ''
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20240508'
#     NV_NVPROF_DEV_PACKAGE = 'cuda-nvprof-12-2=12.2.142-1'
#     NV_LIBNPP_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-12-2=12.2.1.4-1'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl-dev'
#     TCLLIBPATH = '/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.20'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_VERSION = '12.2.5.6-1'
#     COLAB_KERNEL_MANAGER_PROXY_HOST = '172.28.0.12'
#     NVIDIA_PRODUCT_NAME = 'CUDA'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-dev-12-2'
#     USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_VERSION = '12.2.140-1'
#     COLAB_WARMUP_DEFAULTS = '1'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     COLUMNS = '100'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '12.2.2'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-12-2=12.2.5.6-1'
#     NV_CUDA_NSIGHT_COMPUTE_DEV_PACKAGE = 'cuda-nsight-compute-12-2=12.2.2-1'
#     COLAB_RELEASE_TAG = 'release-colab_20240528-060115_RC00'
#     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
#     KMP_TARGET_PORT = '9000'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     KMP_EXTRA_ARGS = ('--logtostderr --listen_host=172.28.0.12 --target_host=172.28.0.12 '
 '--tunnel_background_save_url=https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/cc48301118ce562b961b3c22d803539adc1e0c19/m-s-2ah11whng2q5g '
 '--tunnel_background_save_delay=10s '
 '--tunnel_periodic_background_save_frequency=30m0s '
 '--enable_output_coalescing=true --output_coalescing_required=true')
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-dev-12-2=12.2.1.4-1'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY_LSP_DIRS = '/datalab/web/pyright/typeshed-fallback/stdlib,/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-12-2'
#     COLAB_KERNEL_MANAGER_PROXY_PORT = '6000'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_VERSION = '12.2.1.4-1'
#     ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '77'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_DEV_VERSION = '12.1.2.141-1'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     NV_CUDNN_VERSION = '8.9.6.50'
#     SHLVL = '0'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY = '/usr/colab/bin/language_service'
#     NV_CUDA_LIB_VERSION = '12.2.2-1'
#     NVARCH = 'x86_64'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_DEV = 'libcudnn8-dev=8.9.6.50-1+cuda12.2'
#     NV_CUDA_COMPAT_PACKAGE = 'cuda-compat-12-2'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE = 'libnccl2=2.19.3-1+cuda12.2'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     COLAB_GPU = ''
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     NV_CUDA_NSIGHT_COMPUTE_VERSION = '12.2.2-1'
#     NV_NVPROF_VERSION = '12.2.142-1'
#     LC_ALL = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     COLAB_FILE_HANDLER_ADDR = 'localhost:3453'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl2'
#     COLAB_DEBUG_ADAPTER_MUX_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.19.3-1'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     COLAB_BACKEND_VERSION = 'next'
#     COLAB_CUSTOMIZE_FOR_VM_TYPE = '1'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2


What did you update in the spec file?
Did you use this command !buildozer appclean in Google Colab, after that change?.
If is not that the case, please try to write:

!buildozer appclean
!buildozer android debug or !yes | buildozer -v android debug (I normally use the second option, but
you can choose the command that you prefer)

Why is this neccesary? Because according to this An unofficial Buildozer Users' Guide

If buildozer.spec is changed, the change probably won't propagate into the apk on the next build. After changing the buildozer.spec file (or any of the dependencies) users must do an appclean.

If you already tried this and nothing change, try to check if you have installed libtool, with this command

!sudo apt-get update
!sudo apt-get install libtool

Just like this user adviced.
Just in case, use !buildozer appclean after this.
Cheers!
